# Calculating Account Balance

Tags: wallet, blockchain, balance

Is anyone familiar with how the standard Bitcoin client gathers account balances from the blockchain? I understand that the software will look through the blockchain to calculate the balance, but I was wondering how exactly this is done efficiently.

Comment: possible duplicate: [How balances are calculated?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10050/5406)